# Set @Variable1 within a stored proc by executing @Variable2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures

I want to set the value of @Count by executing @Counter within a Begin Try of a stored procedure.

```
SET @Counter ='SET @Count = (SELECT COUNT(' + @COLUMN + ') FROM ' + @TABLE + ' WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),' + @COLUMN + ') = ''' + @DATATOFIND + ''')'
```

I have tested the above code and it does give me the expected result for populating the @Count variable inside of a normal sql statement outside of a stored procedure.

Once the @Count variable is populated I want to use it in a print statement.

```
PRINT '-- No. of Entries in the ' + @TABLE + ' Table = ' + @Count
```

I have tried to the following two options to get the @Count populated but neither has worked

```
EXEC @Counter

and

EXECUTE sp_executesql (@Counter)
```

UPDATE:

After some more research I tried this:

```
DECLARE @Counter NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @Counter = N'DECLARE @Count NVARCHAR(100); SET @COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(UserId) FROM UserGrp WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),UserId) = ''za02'')'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Counter
Print @Count
```

But I receive this error:
Must declare the scalar variable "@Count"

UPDATE: Workaround / Solution to my situation

```
DECLARE @Counter NVARCHAR(2000)
SET @Counter = 'DECLARE @Count NVARCHAR(100); SET @COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(UserId) FROM UserGrp WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),UserId) = 'to01'); Print '/*  No. of Entries in the UserGrp Table - ' + @Count + ' */''
EXEC (@Counter)
```

This gives me clear information in my result to decide what to do with the created code from the rest of the stored proc

Comment: Have you tried adding an _output_ parameter to the [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) call as shown in Example C on the documentation page? See [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Careful `'...' + @COLUMN + '...'` is dangerously open to injection if you haven't ***properly*** quoted `@COLUMN`.

Comment: ... or `@Table` or parameterized `@DateToFind`.

Comment: Thank you for the cautions! This stored proc is for finding and altering data via SSMS. Once that is done it will be removed =)

I tried working the sp_executesql OUTPUT a little. I am not sure how to incorporate that into my PRINT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL requires careful handling:

```
DECLARE @Counter NVARCHAR(1000);

DECLARE @COUNT BIGINT;
DECLARE @DATATOFIND VARCHAR(100) = 'za02';
DECLARE @TABLE SYSNAME = N'UserGrp';
DECLARE @COLUMN SYSNAME = N'UserId';

SET @Counter = N'SELECT @COUNT = COUNT(<column_name>) 
FROM <table_name> 
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),<column_name>) = @DATATOFIND;';

SET @Counter = REPLACE(@Counter, '<column_name>', QUOTENAME(@COLUMN));
SET @Counter = REPLACE(@Counter, '<table_name>', QUOTENAME(@TABLE));

PRINT @Counter; -- debug

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Counter, 
       N'@DATATOFIND VARCHAR(100), @COUNT BIGINT OUTPUT',
       @DATATOFIND,
       @COUNT OUTPUT;

SELECT @COUNT;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=a8563812a1e10db2d7c49233912db310)**

Minimum:

- params are parameters, not concatenated string
- identifiers(here column/table name) - should be quoted for instance using `QUOTENAME` function
- it is good to print query to see if it doing what is expected
- parameters set inside dynamic query could be passed to outer block by defining them as OUTPUT